# Using slider in custom cell of a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uislider

I have a UITableView which has prototype `cells` which include a slider and a `textfield` next to it. As the slider's value changes, the value inside the `textview` is also changed. It works fine except for when the size of the table increases, the new `cell` generated when scrolling down is already shows the value of the first cell. I do realize that this has something to do with the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` function as the `cells` are reused. How can this be circumvented?

This is the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("infoCell") as! InfoCell

    cell.dressLabel.text = inputArrayFortableView[indexPath.row]

    cell.uiSlider.maximumValue = 100
    cell.uiSlider.minimumValue = 0
    cell.uiSlider.continuous = true
    cell.uiSlider.addTarget(cell, action: #selector(cell.uiSliderSetValue), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    if(cell.DressTextField.text != "")
        {
            cell.uiSlider.setValue(Float(cell.DressTextField.text!)!, animated: true)
        }

    print("outside uisliderSetvalue")
    cell.uiSlider.tag = indexPath.row
    print(cell.uiSlider.tag)

    return cell

}
```

I am attaching a screenshot. Keep in mind the when I scroll downwards, the new cell has the same value as that of the first one, the second cell generated has the same value as that of the second and so on.

[image]

Comment: Show the code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` without it know one will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Because cells are reused, the slider will retain the value from the previous time the cell was used.  Make sure to always initialize the slider in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if cell.DressTextField.text != ""
{
    cell.uiSlider.setValue(Float(cell.DressTextField.text!)!, animated: true)
} else {
    cell.uiSlider.setValue(0, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: The problem with doing this is that when i scroll back up after changing the values, the first slider's value along with other subsequent sliders' values are also set as 0

Comment: You shouldn't use your table cells to store data. When a slider is moved, you should store that value in a model that is independent of the cell. The easiest thing to do is have a property of the view controller that maintains the slider values such as an array and update the value in that array when the slider changes. Also, cellForRowAtIndexPath will read the value from that array when it sets up a cell.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store value of slider to `inputArrayFortableView` when the value is changed. You have to reload this value each time `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` calling because table cells is reuse, it stores old value.